# About input data

Tags: c++

I tried to write a program about finding median of two sequences, it's not hard, but I was stopped buy inputting two sequence part.

Never think about this before, always tried `while(cin>> temp)`, but no idea why this time failed.

When I compile it, the first loop input is OK, but when the second loop began, the compiler give out "vector iterator not dereferencable"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template< class T>
T median(vector<T>& s1, vector<T>& s2) {
T m(0);

auto itr1 = s1.begin();
auto itr2 = s2.begin();
int counts = (s1.size() + s2.size() -1 ) / 2 ;

    for (int i = 0; i < counts; ++i){
        if ((*itr1 < * itr2) && ( itr1+1 != s1.end()))
            ++itr1;
        else
            ++itr2;
    }

    m = (*itr1 + *itr2) / 2;
    return m;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> s1; 
    vector<int> s2;
    cout << " Please input the number in the first sequence " << endl;
    int temp;

    while (cin >> temp) {
        s1.push_back(temp);
    }

    cout << " Please input the number in the second sequence " << endl;
    int temp2;

    while (cin >> temp2){
        s2.push_back(temp2);
    }

    cout << " The median of these two sequences is " << median<int>(s1, s2) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you know when the first sequence is done?

Comment: ( itr1+1 != s1.end())), I think that will be enough.

Comment: the first while loop will never terminate, you must find a way to successfully exit both loops.

Comment: Yep, I was thinking about input some non - int data, then the loop will be terminated.

Comment: @user3399623, describe the problem. What's wrong?

Comment: Your median code doesn't allow for the second argument being shorter than the first — specifically, it fails when the second vector is empty (because it tries to access `*itr2` but that is at the end so accessing it is invalid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use non-number input as sign to stop.
It will stop on any key, not only 'q', but you can add additional checks, etc, ..

```
cout << " Please input first sequence numbers (press 'q' to finish)" << endl;

while (cin >> temp)
    s1.push_back(temp);

cin.clear();

// ignore all symbols before '\n'
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

cout << " Please input second sequence numbers (press 'q' to finish)" << endl;

while (cin >> temp)
   s2.push_back(temp);
```